# Need help debugging writing to a file in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I'm writing a code that discretizes a circle and then gives back what points would be in an interval specified by the user. Using variables x,y, and theta, it writes the values of y and theta as they should be to the file info.dat, but writes that x is zero no matter what I do. It has no problem writing to points.dat either. Btw all variables were properly defined from the start as either allocatable, target, pointer, etc.

```
open(unit=2, file="points.DAT")

print*, 'Please enter the reference angle of the arc in degrees, number of points on the arc, and radius of the arc.'
read(*,*) a, n, r
a = a * pi / 180


allocate(x(1:n),y(1:n),theta(1:n))
do i = 1,n
    theta(i:i) = a*(i-1)/n
    x(i:i) = r * cos(theta(i:i))
    y(i:i) = r * sin(theta(i:i))
    xcoord(i:i) => x(i:i)
    ycoord(i:i) => y(i:i)
    angle(i:i) => theta(i:i)        
write(2,*) 'x',i,'=',x(i:i),'y',i,'=',y(i:i), 'theta', i,'=', theta(i:i)    
end do
deallocate(x,y,theta)   
    close(2)

    open(unit=3, file="info.DAT")
print*, 'Please specify the interval of interest between 0 and 360 degrees'
read(*,*) b, c
b = b * pi / 180
c = c * pi / 180

do i = 1, n
    if (any(b <= angle(i:i) .and. angle(i:i) <= c)) then
        write(3,*) 'x', i, '=', xcoord(i:i), 'y', i, '=', ycoord(i:i), 'theta', i, '=', angle(i:i)
    end if
end do
close(3)
```

Comment: It will probably help anyone trying to help you to show the declarations of the variables in your code, in fact to post an MCVE -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @High a rank 1 dim (1) array is (almost) the same as a (scalar) element 
for computation (at least the simple uses here) and I/O, but not for pointer association (apparently using bounds-remapping which is NOT F95) nor argument passing (not used here) because in those cases rank must match (as well as type and kind).

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't show it `xcoord ycoord angle` must be declared as `POINTER`. You set them to point to each single-element slice of `x() y() theta()` in turn,
leave them pointing to the N'th elements, and then deallocate the underlying arrays so the **pointers are now undefined** (point to freed memory).

If you have debugging options on your compiler (or possibly runtime) and use them, they should definitely detect the accesses to 1..n-1 
while the pointer association is set to (n:n), and might detect that even (n) is invalid because of the deallocation. It appears by good luck the memory formerly used 
by `x` has been clobbered by something else but by bad luck `y` and `theta` still have their values.